# How to use and configure ADC of STM32F407G-Discovery with nanoFramework?

Tags: c#, stm32, adc, nanoframework, chibios

I try to use ChibiOS presetted ADCs. Available channels following the [specification](https://docs.nanoframework.net/content/community-targets/stm32f4-discovery.html):

- PC1, ADC1 IN11
- PC2 ADC1 IN12
- PA6 ADC2 IN6
- PA7 ADC2 IN7
- PB0 ADC2 IN8
- Temp Sensor ADC1
- VrefInt ADC1
- Vbatt ADC1

*Presetted ADCs from ChibiOS' [build source](https://github.com/nanoframework/nf-Community-Targets/blob/main/ChibiOS/ST_STM32F4_DISCOVERY/target_system_device_adc_config.cpp) (target_system_device_adc_config.cpp):*

```
#include <sys_dev_adc_native_target.h>
 
const NF_PAL_ADC_PORT_PIN_CHANNEL AdcPortPinConfig[] = {
 
    // ADC1
    {1, GPIOC, 1, ADC_CHANNEL_IN11},
    {1, GPIOC, 2, ADC_CHANNEL_IN12},
 
    // ADC2
    {2, GPIOA, 6, ADC_CHANNEL_IN6},
    {2, GPIOA, 7, ADC_CHANNEL_IN7},
    {2, GPIOB, 0, ADC_CHANNEL_IN8},
 
    // these are the internal sources, available only at ADC1
    {1, NULL, 0, ADC_CHANNEL_SENSOR},
    {1, NULL, 0, ADC_CHANNEL_VREFINT},
    {1, NULL, 0, ADC_CHANNEL_VBAT},
};
 
const int AdcChannelCount = ARRAYSIZE(AdcPortPinConfig);
```

How to use ADCs? Is there some way to configure ADC in C# code? I would appreciate any help. Thank you

I wrote this code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Device.Adc;
 
namespace ADCMeasure
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static int adcValue;
 
        public static void Main()
        {
            AdcController adcController = new AdcController();
            AdcChannel pa6Channel = adcController.OpenChannel(6);
 
            while (true)
            {
                adcValue = pa6Channel.ReadValue();
                double ratio = pa6Channel.ReadRatio();
                Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(adcValue)}: {adcValue}; {nameof(ratio)}: {ratio}; MaxValue: {adcController.MaxValue}; MinValue: {adcController.MinValue}");
                Thread.Sleep( 1000 );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and have debug console output: `adcValue: 1695; ratio: 0.41343101; MaxValue: 4095; MinValue: 0`

It corresponds real 2.7V on PA6.

If I change the channel to 7th (`adcController.OpenChannel(7)`),

I have `adcValue: 4; ratio: 0; MaxValue: 4095; MinValue: 0` and 0V on PA7.

If I connect PA7 (7th channel) to external 2V I have no changes in debug console but I see this 2V on PA7 by voltmeter, it would be about `adcValue: 1260` and `ratio: 0.30769`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index that you use when calling `adcController.OpenChannel(6)` is the index of the `AdcPortPinConfig[]` array.
By using 7 you're reading the ADC_CHANNEL_VBAT. (mind that's 0 based)